# Inserting new column using loop and encountering error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a column based on a date in cell B1. I have various columns with dates in row 2; however, my supplied code throws off error 1004 when I run it. I believe this is due to the loop eventually running into a cell in row 2 that is empty, presumably because the date in cell B1 is more recent than all the other dates. How can I make it insert a column to the right of the last column with a date in this case?

Here is what I have so far as supplied by user "The GridLock":

```
Sub DateLoopTest()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    'Loop from [B2] offset 0 to 1,2... -> then stop at [b2].offset(0,i) 
    Do Until (DateValue([b1]) < DateValue(IIf(IsDate([b2].Offset(0, i)), [b2].Offset(0, i), [b1])))
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    [b2].Offset(0, i).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    [b2].Offset(0, i).Value = [b1]
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share what your beginning sheet looks like as well as the desired result?

Comment: I've got a list of titles on column A. Starting with Column B on row 2 there are numerous dates. I want to insert a new column into sheet in its order based off the date (in cell B1). The above code does that; however, it has an error when the date being inserted is the largest date listed.

Comment: So, you want to go through row 2 starting from the "B" column and insert one column to the right if the date in that cell is bigger than in "B2"?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use variables that mean something and avoid using brackets for the ranges.  You can't test the logic if you can't identify the range.  Your logic doesn't test if there is a date greater than your starting point or if the date already exists in the range.  This is a starting point and you can modify to test other logic, but it won't give you an error.

```
Sub DateLoopTest()
    Dim LC As Long
    Dim MaxDate As Date
    Dim TargetDate As Date
    LC = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim HdrRng As Range
    Set HdrRng = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, LC))
    MaxDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(HdrRng)

    TargetDate = Cells(1, 2)

    i = 2

    If TargetDate < MaxDate And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(HdrRng, TargetDate) = 0 Then
        Do Until TargetDate > Cells(2, i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
            Cells(2, i).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Cells(2, i).Offset(0, 1) = TargetDate

    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(HdrRng, TargetDate) > 0 Then
            Z = HdrRng.Find(TargetDate).Column
            Cells(2, Z + 1).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Cells(2, Z + 1) = TargetDate
    End If

End Sub
```